# Kernel, Basis and Column Space

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

If a matrix $A$ has row reduced form

$A=$$\begin{pmatrix} 1&3&0&3 \\ 0&0&1&-1 \\ 0&0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$

then the kernel of the linear map $T : \mathbb{R}^4 → \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $T(x) = Ax$ has basis $$(−3,1,0,0), (−3, 0, 1, 1).$$

> How do I prove or disprove the claim regarding the kernel?

Any help is appreciated guys. Also, how can I show that columns 2 and 4 forms a basis for the column space?

Answer (score 1):

Use the rank-nullity theorem, which says that

$\dim R^4 = \dim ker(A) + \dim rank (A)$

Here $\dim ker(A) = 4 - 2 = 2$. Your two vectors are linearly independent and so form a basis of $ker(A)$.

Comment: But why does it follow that since $dim(Ker(A))=2$, and my 2 vectors are linearly independent, it forms a basis of $Ker(A)$?  What's the relationship between the dimension and it forming a basis? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Car a linearly independent set of $k$ vectors in a space of dimension $k$ must be a basis. Generally any linearly independent set in any vector space can be extended to a basis by adding zero or more vectors, and because of the definition of "dimension," if you've already got $k$ vectors, then you don't need to add any more. So if you know the dimension of $\ker(A)$ all you need to do are verify that the vectors are linearly independent and that they are in $\ker(A)$.

Comment: @Car for similar reasons, this answer allows you to verify the dimension of the column space of $A$, and hence your second question reduces to showing only that the two indicated vectors are in that space (which is clear; they're literally columns of $A$, and not more general combinations of columns of $A$) and that they are linearly independent.

Comment: @Car I further note that the dimension of $\ker(A)$ does not appear to be assumed in the problem, so you may need to perform a calculation to compute it. Once you know it, you're in the above setup, even if your algorithm for computing $\dim \ker(A)$ somehow produced a different basis for $\ker(A)$.

Comment: @leslietownes Thank you for your reply. Then I suppose both questions are true? (Regarding basis and column column space)

Comment: @Car Yes although I do not see a way of just "reading" this off of the matrix without actually first computing a basis for the nullspace or the column space via established methods and thus providing the necessary inputs to the above dimensional analysis.

Answer (score 0):

The reduced matrix is $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1&3&0&3 \\ 0&0&1&-1 \\ 0&0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$ and if we want to find the generator of the Kernel we have to solve the system $A\underline x=\underline0$:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1&3&0&3 \\ 0&0&1&-1 \\ 0&0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}\underline x=\underline 0\implies \begin{pmatrix} 1&3&0&3 \\ 0&0&1&-1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\\w \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}\implies$$
$$\begin{cases}x+3y+3w=0\\z-w=0 \end{cases}\implies z=w=t\in\mathbb R,y=s\in\mathbb R,x=-3t-3s.$$
So we can state that $\operatorname{Ker}(F)=\Big\langle\begin{pmatrix}-3\\1\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}-3\\0\\1\\1 \end{pmatrix} \Big\rangle$.